# How loop through an object array and showcase separate HTML elements one by one

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In my react application, i'm having an object array and the size of it will vary. The sample array would look like,

```
const Array = [
  {
    rowData: [...],
    fieldMapping: {...}
  },
  {
    rowData: [...],
    fieldMapping: {...}
  },
  {
    rowData: [...],
    fieldMapping: {...}
  }
]
```

I need to showcase separate custom elements for each objects in above array. Here I have only 3 objects. But the array size can change. So I should use a loop to render those elements by passing the objects as props. But can we do that in react?
My sample JSX code is

```
return (
<>
 <Drawer title="Overall Restoration Progress" placement="top" closable={false} onClose={() =>
            dispatch(setGlacierRestoreProgressEnable(false))} visible={glacierRestoreProgresEnable} height={'auto'}>
  <Collapse defaultActiveKey={['1']} onChange={callback}>
    
    <Panel header="Download Request 1" key="1">
      <CustomElement source={Array[0]} />; 
    </Panel>

    <Panel header="Download Request 2" key="2">
      <CustomElement source={Array[1]} />; 
    </Panel>

    <Panel header="Download Request 3" key="3">
      <CustomElement source={Array[2]} />; 
    </Panel>

  </Collapse>
</Drawer>
</>
)
```

How can i put above code in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

there you go. reading [this react document about listing](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) will help.

```
<Collapse {/* ... */}>
  {Array.map((item, index) => <Panel key={index}><CustomElement source={item} /></Panel>}
</Collapse>
```